# Continuous Animation of Vector Drawable in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector drawable xml file linked to an Image View.
Now the animation run only once.
How can I continuously animate the result?
Someone please help me to make this work.
Thanks!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {  

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)    
            animateView(avdImage)    
        }
    }    
    private fun animateView(view: ImageView) {
        when (val drawable = view.drawable) {
            is AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat -> {
                drawable.start()
            }    
            is AnimatedVectorDrawable -> {
                drawable.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough just to add:
android:repeatCount = "-1"
to your XML file which is handling the rotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).